# Connect to server using SFTP and a public SSH key using FileZilla on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp, filezilla, ssh-keys

Is it possible to generate an SSH key on a Windows machine and then use that key to connect to a server using SFTP via FileZilla?

This is all working with my Mac, but I have a client that is stuck in a Windows environment. Our server does not have traditional FTP access and I need to get him connected.

Details would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

FileZilla uses the PuTTY suite of tools for its SSH implementation. PuTTY supports using public keys, so by default so does FileZilla. It's as simple as downloading and running [Pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and importing your key, or generating a new one using [PuTTYgen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

You can also manually specify a key file using menu *Edit* → *Settings*, item *Connection* (first item in the left panel)

- [FileZilla HowTo Wiki Entry](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto)
- [Pageant documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant)
- [PuTTYgen documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey)

Comment: anything special regarding synology devices and FileZilla? cause I can ssh without issues to it from terminal but setting up new connection using the same key renders: "FATAL ERROR: Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server"

Answer (score 22):

If the private SSH key already exists, this can be done from within FileZilla, without the need to install extra software. Simply go to menu *Edit* → *Settings* → *Connection* → *FTP* → *SFTP*.

Click button <kbd>Add key file</kbd> and add your private key there. It will convert the key for you.

Comment: Minor correction: You need to add the _private_ key to FileZilla. The public key must be present on the server and the private key must be present on the client (i.e. FileZilla).

Comment: Is there any way to get FileZilla on Mac to show hidden files?  I can't get it to navigate to ~/.ssh/

Comment: Answered my own question: http://superuser.com/questions/302732/filezilla-on-mac-os-x-cant-open-ssh-directory-to-get-my-keyfile

Comment: It does not allow me to connect to my sftp server by using public key auth since FileZilla knows nothing about public key. openssh server knows only about public key.
Filezilla also prints in connection log that 0 keypairs loaded from file.

Comment: @jchavannes: Like you said for Mac press: `Shift`-`Command`-`Period` while in the finder window

Answer (score 1):

For a long time, FileZilla already has per-site key configuration. So it's not necessary to go to global *Settings* to add the key.

On "Login" (site manager) dialog:

- select *SFTP* for Protocol
- enter your *Host*
- Select *Key file* for *Logon type*
- enter your *User*
- *Browse* for your *Key file*

[image]