# FileZilla on Mac OS X can't open .ssh directory to get my keyfile

Tags: macos, sftp, filezilla

I'm trying to log on to my Amazon EC2 cloud server instance with FileZilla, 
To do this I need to specify a keyfile for SFTP over SSH,

However, FileZilla in OS X can't open files in hidden directories.

Like for most Mac users, mine are located in `~/.ssh`. But alas, when I click on 'Add Keyfile' in 'SFTP Settings' under 'Preferences', the Finder window won't show hidden files.

A bit of research turned up [this](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=20220), and I do have my Finder set up to view hidden files, 
so... what's up FileZilla?

I would really not like to have to move the contents of my `.ssh` to `~`. I'd rather not take the easy way out and just use some other client.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In any Open or Save dialog in OS X, simply press `Shift-Command-Period` to display hidden files and folders.

http://www.macworld.com/article/142884/2009/09/106seehidden.html

Comment: Brilliant. forgive the turnaround on selecting this as the answer & tyty.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad that it solved your problem :)

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try switching the folder view. For some reason this trick only worked on 3 of the 4 views (didn't work on the one with multiple panes)

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively to displaying hidden files/folder, you may find it easier to navigate there directly.

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> will display a dialogue box to enter the path. Then enter `~/.ssh`, and you're in.

If you enter the path to a *file* in an Open/Save window and press enter, it will choose that file to be opened/saved.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me in 2022 :)