# Missing option in FileZilla: Key file authentication

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp, filezilla, ssh-keys

Where is the option "log in with key file"?

Please have a look at the attached *image* at the bottom.

System: Gnome desktop Linux, CentOS 7

FileZilla Client: version: 3.7.4.1

Build information:

```
Compiled for: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Compiled on: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Build date: 2014-04-09
Compiled with: gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20131106 (Red Hat 4.8.2-3)
Compiler flags: -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -Wall -g -fexceptions -std=gnu++11

Linked against:
wxWidgets: 2.8.12
GnuTLS: 3.3.29
SQLite: 3.7.17

Operating system:
Name: Linux 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 x86_64
Version: 3.10
```

Image of the options:

[image: Image of the Options]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to server using SFTP and public ssh key using FileZilla on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/180221/connect-to-server-using-sftp-and-public-ssh-key-using-filezilla-on-windows)

Comment: sadly not, shown in the attached image

Comment: Your image has nothing to do with your problem. Check the answer by @AkarshSatija.

Comment: thanks I was just confused because the other is about windos and im on linux

Comment: So please accept that your question is duplicate.

Comment: It`s somehow misleading and just a workaround for my question. My question in first place is: Why doesn't FileZilla linux support the key location connection type in the front GUI? Im working the most time on Windows where I simply fill in the key location. Now im supposed to add them in the backend. I guess more ppl will encounter this problem on Linux and the other question is marked as windows.

Comment: Sadly I can`t mark the question as duplicate because my rep ist too low.

Comment: I do not undertand your comment. What do you mean by *"front GUI"* and what by *"backend"*? Do you mean that in Linux FileZilla, there's no *Edit > Settings > Connection > SFTP > Add key file*?

Comment: sorry for my unclear comment. 
The option is missing in my "Site Manager" where I used to find it.
can you mark my question as proofed duplicate

Comment: There is no option in Site Manager for public key authentication. In any version of FileZilla.

Comment: Don't you see a button like *"Yes this [duplicate question] answers my problem"*?

Comment: Sadly only "This question may already have an answer here:" sadly no button insight. I guess because I was too fast with:"This is no duplicate" at the start.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That version is v3.7.4.1, and that one is from 2014.

For private key use, you will need at least v3.14.0-rc1 2015-09-04, but sadly [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7 doesn't come with that version. You will need to compile manually.

More information is in *[Version history](https://filezilla-project.org/versions.php)*.

Comment: All versions of FileZilla that support SFTP do support public key authentication. The oldest only via Pageant agent. Later via global settings. And even later directly with session-specific key. All this is covered in the [duplicate question](https://superuser.com/q/180221/213663). This answer is redundant and misleading. – Obviously upgrading to the latest version is always the right thing to do.