# SFTP access information

Tags: networking, ssh, ftp, network-shares, sftp

I am have clients sending me they data over the email (csv files) so I can then do what I need to for them with it. Obviously, this is not the best secure way to transfer data and I am thinking of using SFTP, however, I am not sure how difficult for them will be to access the SFTP. My idea is to give them SFTP credentials so they can log in via e.g WinSCP, FIlezilla etc and upload the required data for me to process it, but, I am new to networking and I am not sure what they would have to exactly do to allow they network to allow access the SFTP I give them? I read something about OpenSHH and opening port 22? Please can someone explain what would need to be done?

Comment: Does this work for you? [Connect to server using SFTP and a public SSH key using FileZilla on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/180221/connect-to-server-using-sftp-and-a-public-ssh-key-using-filezilla-on-windows)

Comment: If ease of use is your main concern, using a browser/cloud-based file exchange service is probably a better solution for you and your clients (you can use a service provider you trust or host it yourself).

Comment: SFTP sits on top of SSH and uses a single tcp connection to port 22 making it very easy to handle - and work well with NAT and firewalls.  Generally it will "just work" unless specific measures have been put in place to lock down a network much more tightly then is typical - in short, for most people no changes will need to be made to their network to use an sftp client.

Comment: They would omly need to open port 22/if they were providing an SFTP server (not acting as an SFTP client which seems to be what you are wanting)

Comment: thanks all, I tested the davidgo option and it looks like opening port 22 is enough but also had to allow the IP to access the sftp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure sharing on a small Windows 10 network since HomeGroup is gone?](https://superuser.com/questions/1328942/how-to-configure-sharing-on-a-small-windows-10-network-since-homegroup-is-gone)